# Policy Based Design - Ideomatic way to deal with multitude of types, e.g. storing them in a container, iterating, etc

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++14, c++17

In the hello world example of policy based design from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) we use a common interface `HelloWorld` and configure it with different policies through templates - so far so good:

```c++
int main() {
  // Example 1
  typedef HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyEnglish>
      HelloWorldEnglish;

  HelloWorldEnglish hello_world;
  hello_world.Run();  // Prints "Hello, World!".

  // Example 2
  // Does the same, but uses another language policy.
  typedef HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyGerman>
      HelloWorldGerman;

  HelloWorldGerman hello_world2;
  hello_world2.Run();  // Prints "Hallo Welt!".
}
```

This is all very nice and elegant, but what is the idiomatic way of managing / storing a collection of such configurable objects? For example, one would like to write

```c++
std::vector< some_magic_type > seasons_greetings;  // What is the common type specifying the public interface only?
seasons_greetings.push_back(hello_world);  // which is of type HelloWorldEnglish
seasons_greetings.push_back(hello_world2); // which is of type HelloWorldGerman
for (greeting : seasons_greetings) {
  greeting.Run() // access only the public interface
}
```

In designing interfaces as base classes and deriving specialised implementations from them, I don't have this problem - I can always store pointers to the base class type - but I need to spell out all implementations leading to a whole lot of derived classes.
Policy Based Design promised to alleviate the explosion of derived classes that comes with this by using templates to mix and match behavior. But I pay for this with a whole lot of different types.

There must be an idiomatic way to deal with this. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

P.S.
I admit that I did not buy the book, but you might have guessed already.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596912/when-to-prefer-templated-policy-based-design-over-non-templated-inheritance-base) suggests storing a collection implies an inheritance based design, but does it really?

Comment: `HelloWorldEnglish` and `HelloWorldGerman` are two distinct, unrelated classes. If you want to work with them polymorphically, you'd have to use the techniques of polymorphism to achieve that - e.g. derive them from a common base class with `Run` virtual method. Policy-based design neither helps nor hurts that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that polymorphism has it's place as does policy based design. My application would benefit greatly from being able to use the templated approach - I have lots of variants and only need to store a select few of them in a container. C++17 gives us `std::variant` and that can be stored in a `std::vector`. So it can be done and I'm sure someone out there has an elegant solution for this.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - the solution I eventually came up with below is probably what you suggested early on. It just took me a while to appreciate the comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a solution I found after pondering the comments again - key seems to combine the best of both worlds, polymorphism and policies - who would have thought ....

By introducing a common base class that defines only the public interface of the behavior class and then deriving the behavior class from that and the policies, I can get exactly what I want:

```c++
class HelloWorldInterface {
    public:
    // Behavior method.
    void Run() const {
        run();
    }
    private:
    virtual void run() const = 0;
};

template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy>
class HelloWorld : public HelloWorldInterface, private OutputPolicy, private LanguagePolicy {
 private:
   using OutputPolicy::Print;
   using LanguagePolicy::Message;
   void run() const override final {
       Print(Message());
   }
};
```

Then, I can write basically what I wanted from the beginning:

```c++
int main() {
  // Example 1
  using HelloWorldEnglish =  HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyEnglish>;

  // Example 2
  // Does the same, but uses another language policy.
  using HelloWorldGerman =  HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyGerman>;

  HelloWorldEnglish hello_world;
  HelloWorldGerman hello_world2;

  std::vector<const HelloWorldInterface*> greetings{&hello_world, &hello_world2};

  for (auto x : greetings) {
      x -> Run();
  }
}
```

This way, one gets a single public interface that exposes behaviours resulting from an arbitrary combination of policies. Looks trivial now, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with unrelated classes you can use [std:variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in combination with [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Example ( simply extend the main function from the original example )

```
    using Variant = std::variant< HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyEnglish>, HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyGerman> >;
    std::vector< Variant > seasons_greetings; 
    seasons_greetings.push_back(hello_world);
    seasons_greetings.push_back(hello_world2);
    for (auto& greeting : seasons_greetings) {
        std::visit( [](auto& what){ what.Run(); }, greeting );
    }
```

The bad side: You have to know all possible combinations of policies which can be really uncomfortable. But you can use some meta template stuff to create all variant types by giving type lists for each used policy and the template will generate all combinations, which is not such a big hack.

Comment: Thank you, that is nice! I'll go on hunting the "meta template stuff to create all variant types". Btw, wouldn't a variadic template also be an option? I don't have a vector, but could still iterate over the collection of arguments with a nice fold expression.

Comment: @JReichardt Instead of "thank you", you should up vote. And if my post answers your question, you should accept it... thats how we "pay" for help on SO

Comment: sorry. Upvoted. The std::variant solution is a possibility but comes with the associated drawbacks you already hinted at. If you permit, I'd like to keep the question open for a couple more days to see if another possible solution appears, ok?

Comment: @JReichardt You choice :-) Other option is to use a common base class per policy and drive via vtable. But that is a bit the opposite of policy based design. But if it fits your needs... it will work :-)